# Saving audio content Uri in sharedpreference to play later

Tags: android, android-intent, sharedpreferences, android-mediaplayer, android-contentprovider

I am trying to design an `Alarm` app where `Audio` is played when the device is shaken.

I am selecting the `Audio` from file system using "ACTION_GET_CONTENT" in `Intent` with `ActivityForResult`. I am able to fetch the `content uri`, saving it in `SharedPreference` and playing it with `MediaPlayer` on a different `Activity` passing the `URI` in `Intent`.

But, once I close my app and reopen it and try to play the `Audio` from the `URI` in `SharedPrederence`, the `Audio` is not played.

What can be done so that I can play Audio from saved `content uri` in `SharedPreference`?

**Code to fetch uri from Storage:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("audio/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);


@Override 
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data){

  if(requestCode == 1){

    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){

        //the selected audio.
        String aud_uri = data.getData();

        String quri = aud_uri.toString();



        //Write to shared preferences

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putString("quake_uri",quri);
    editor.commit();
        //

    }
  }
```

**Code to fetch from sharedpreference**

```
sharedPref = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String quri = sharedPref.getString("quake_uri", "defaultString");
```

**Code to play audio in different activity after passing uri through intent**

```
String audio = getIntent().getStringExtra("audio");
Uri uri = Uri.parse(audio);
Mediaplayer player = new MediaPlayer();
```

...

**Logcat when audio is not played**

```
05-26 12:53:44.103: E/MediaPlayer(17183): Unable to create media player
05-26 12:53:44.103: V/Error(17183): setDataSource failed.: status=0x80000000
05-26 12:53:44.113: W/System.err(17183): java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed.: status=0x80000000
05-26 12:53:44.113: W/System.err(17183):    at android.media.MediaPlayer.nativeSetDataSource(Native Method)
05-26 12:53:44.113: W/System.err(17183):    at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1061)
```

I am passing the uri to a service which in turn opens the activity to play audio with uri passed from the service with intent

Comment: Share some possible code!

Comment: are you sure passing the string with "audio" key? I can't see that in code.

Comment: Yes.,.,.,.dialogIntent.putExtra("audio", AUDI);
     startActivity(dialogIntent);
The audio is playing when I do not close the app..,.,but If i close and reopen or activity is started from background service, the audio is not working,.,.,the logcat is given for that

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this for a while, I managed to get it working by replacing 'Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT' with 'Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT'.

It seems that if you want the reference to this file to be valid for multiple sessions you need to use the open document action.
I found this out in the following Android documentation: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider

I realize that you asked this question a few years ago, but hopefully this information is still of some use.